# django-simple-menu integration with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate django third-party app with a bootstrap template. This third party app provides dynamically generated menu for website. This app is called django-simple-menu. Following is a code to access the menu from Django template and it works well.

## base.html

```
{% load menu %}{% generate_menu %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}No title set{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block headextra %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>User Menu</h1>
        {% with menu=menus.user %}{% include "menu.html" %}{% endwith %}

        <h1>Main Menu</h1>
        {% with menu=menus.main %}{% include "menu.html" %}{% endwith %}

        <h1>Example Menu</h1>
        {% with menu=menus.ExampleMenu %}{% include "menu.html" %}{% endwith %}

        <hr>

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

## menu.html

```
<ul>
    {% for item in menu %}
    {% if item.separator %}<li>------------</li>{% endif %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            {% for child in item.children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
     <br> <br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I am trying to integrate it with following place in bootstrap where it provide a static navigation bar. I want it dynamically populated. Any help would be great.I am not familiar with CSS and very little experience with HTML and JS.

```
 <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I am at a stage where only dropdown menu is not working. I was able to integrate normal menu. Below is my code if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>

          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% for item in menu %}
                    {#% if item.visible %#}
                        {% if item.separator %}<li class="divider-vertical"></li>{% endif %}
                        <li class="{% if item.selected %} active{% endif %}{% if item.children %} dropdown{% endif %}" id="top-menu-{{ item.slug }}">
                        {% if item.children %}
                            <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                        {% endif %}
                            {% if item.icon %}  <i class="icon-{{ item.icon }} icon-white"></i>&nbsp;  {% endif %}
                            {{ item.title }}
                        {% if item.children %} <span class="caret"></span> {% endif %}
                            </a>
                        {% if item.children %}
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    {% for child in item.children %}
                                        <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {#% endif %#}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I am wondering if someone can guide me on how to integrate the menu in this for loop without losing the look and feel of the bootstrap project that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a new template and include it after the `{% if item.children %}` tag. Something like:

```
<li class="{% if item.selected %}active{% endif %} {% if item.children %}dropdown dropdown-toggle{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">
        {{item.title}}
    </a>
    {% if item.children %}
        {% include 'base/navbar-sub.html' with items=item.children %}
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

And then, yout navbar-sub would be something like:

```
{% load menu %}
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% generate_menu %}
    {% for item in items %}
        {% if item.visible %}
            <li class="{% if item.selected %}active{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                {{item.title}}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```